# How do I use get_query_var() within plguin code

Tags: query

I am tring to access the author's id using

```
get_query_var('author')
```

, but this only seems to work on the page, not within plguin code.

How do I access this from within plugin code?

Answer (score 2):

`get_query_var` works within any code, theme or plugin. But it will only return meaningful data after the query has been processed. So, use it on the init hook or later.